# jquery - not able to replace siblings div with id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery script that I do not fully understand. I was wondering why I cannot replace the siblings('div') with a class or id? I think my code doesn't work properly. What I was trying to do is replace some content with a button click, and then the second content, replace it again with the second function.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.btnClick').on('click', function () {
    var faculty_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + faculty_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
  });
  $('.btnClick2').on('click', function () {
    var department_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + department_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h4>Search courses</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <br>
                    <ul>
                        {% for faculty in faculties %}
                            <li class="btnClick" id="fac_{{ faculty.pk }}">{{ faculty.name }}</li>
                            <ul>
                                {% for department in faculty.department_set.all %}
                                    <li class="btnClick2" id="dep_{{ department.pk }}">{{ department.name }}</li>
                                    <ul>
                                        {% for study in studies %}
                                            {% if study.department == department %}
                                                <li>{{ study.name }}</li>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div>
                        <h3>All courses</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {% for course in courses %}
                                <li>
                                    <a class="first" href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% for faculty in faculties %}
                        <div id="fac_{{ faculty.pk }}_tab" style="display:none;">
                            <h3> {{ faculty.name }} courses</h3>
                            <ul>
                                {% for department in faculty.department_set.all %}
                                    {% for study in studies %}
                                        {% if study.department == department %}
                                            {% for course in courses %}
                                                {% if course.study_programme == study %}
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="first"
                                                           href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for faculty in faculties %}
                        <ul>
                            {% for department in faculty.department_set.all %}
                                <div id="dep_{{ department.pk }}_tab" style="display:none;">
                                    <h3>Department of {{ department.name }} courses</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                        {% for study in studies %}
                                            {% if study.department == department %}
                                                {% for course in courses %}
                                                    {% if course.study_programme == study %}
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="first"
                                                               href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the html as well...

Comment: @void Did. I am not sure if its understandable since it's mostly django.

Comment: What class or id did you try to use instead of div

Comment: @DannM so what exactly is not working here?

Comment: @void all courses get replaced by faculties, but faculties dont get replaced by the departments, when I press on a department, they all show one under another

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/r7aATBS.png

Comment: @DannM can you put this in a working code snippet or jsfiddle? Maybe create a dummy HTML?

Comment: @void not really. Dont have the knowledge to do it without django tags.

Comment: When you view the page in a browser, right click somewhere and select View Source. That will get you the rendered HTML. We're not going to setup a django server with all of your data. We're volunteers.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KsE0Qvmq Sorry, here it is.